# Can't connect Kyocera Event phone to Intel XDK

Tags: usb-debugging

I'm trying to connect my Kyocera Event phone to Intel XDK, but I only get the `No device connected` message in Intel XDK.

[image: The "No device connected" message in Intel XDK.]

I have tried turning on USB debugging under `Settings>Developer Options` and clicking Build 8 times under `Settings>About Phone` and installing my phone's device drivers on my computer and restarting my phone and computer after making those changes.

Comment: What is the phone model?

Comment: The phone model is Kyocera event